# How to prevent appending of 'timestamp' parameter to an image url?

Tags: timestamp

**Question:**
How to prevent appending of 'timestamp' parameter to an image url when we fetch the image from a different site?

This is the url I am passing to the image src:
http://developer.tmsimg.com/movieposters/v5/AllPhotos/9479060/p9479060_p_v5_aa.jpg?api_key=xxx

But when I run my site in browser the timestamp parameter is getting appended and the image is not fetching. Because the url I am getting in inspecting the HTML element is:
http://developer.tmsimg.com/movieposters/v5/AllPhotos/9479060/p9479060_p_v5_aa.jpg?api_key=xxx?timestamp=1381754521855

I want to remove the timestamp parameter from getting appended to the url.
Can any one help me to solve this issue. If so it will be a time saver and heart full.

Comment: I solved it myself. For any one struggling with the same issue.

Check your JQuery file which you had included. The timestamp was appending from the JQuery file which I was using. I removed it and the images are loading smoothly. :)